# Changing the position of new applications in the launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

Having the apps in a specific location on the launcher is useful for using the Super+# shortcut.  However, whenever I launch a new application (an app that isn't locked), it always ends up in the 6th position instead of being appended to the end of the launcher.

Is there any way to change where new apps show up in the launcher so it does not alter my Super+6-9 shortcuts.

[image]